# jQuery Resize - Initializing Function (If parameter issues)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement, window-resize

The code below just executes a function when the viewport width (a var) is over a set width.

```
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();

function refit__slider__height(){
    var fitted__height  = $('#promobanner__wrap').height() - 150;

    $('#promobanner--slider').height( fitted__height );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( viewportWidth > 767 ){
        refit__slider__height();
    }
});

// for the window resize
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ( viewportWidth > 767 ){
        refit__slider__height();
    }
});
```

However I have noticed that when the if statement is below 767 then gets resized above 767 the JS condition is not caught, a page refresh has to occur for the if condition to match.

Has anyone come across this? Or no of a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reinitialize viewportwidth again in resize event like,

```
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( viewportWidth > 767 ){
        refit__slider__height();
    }
    $(window).resize(function() {
        viewportWidth = $(this).width();// re-init width on resizing window
        if ( viewportWidth > 767 ){
            refit__slider__height();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: one could actually add a trigger after the event binder: `$(window).resize(...}).resize();`

Comment: It is not necessary as he is checking that condition in `document.ready()`

Comment: Thanks @RohanKumar! It makes more sense now, However what benefit would putting inside a doc ready be?